# check that outgoing network is open on port 443, with vb6

Tags: winapi, vb6, network-programming

in Visual Basic 6

How can i check that communication to port 443 is opened for network requests?

I must NOT use any 3rd party controls / activeX / OCX, so I'm looking for ways to send / receive an https or just make a connection to a server which is serving on 443,
using windows (2k/2k3/xp/7/vista) API calls.

There is a known server I can check against.
(or, for that matter, https://google.com/accounts)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that I can think of. One being to use [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), specifically the [InternetOpenUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Another way is to use [WinHttp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can use the function [WinHttpOpenRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#Opening_a_request). You can also use it as a [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384079%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object. Here are a few examples:

http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=72

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa384072

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar for ping in the past, perhaps you can modify it to use telnet to post a http get on 443. This code calls the ping command and directs the output to a file

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call objShell.run("%comspec% /c ping 127.0.0.1 > c:\ping.log", 0, False)
'code to read results from ping.log here
```

You may also want to look at the winsock control. It may already be installed on the client computers.

Comment: thanks, but i prefer not to rely at all on local resources. also, what ping has to do with specific arbitrary ports? telnet maybe. still, it's external, and i can't take any risks with this prog.